# Swift Optional of Optional

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

For a project of mine, I have to create a proxy AppDelegate that will forward calls to a another AppDelegate.

UIApplicationDelegate havs a `var window: UIWindow?`. My question is, why can't I do this:

```
private lazy var realAppDelegate: UIApplicationDelegate = {
    return AppDelegate()
}()

var window: UIWindow? {
    get {
        return realAppDelegate.window
    }
    set {
        realAppDelegate.window = newValue
    }
}
```

The problem with that code is that `realAppDelegate.window` is a `UIWindow??`.

Does anybody know why?

Comment: Some more information on nested optionals: [Swift Blog Post](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=12) and [a related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27225232/two-or-more-optionals-in-swift/27226589#27226589)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25175544/uiwindow-does-not-have-member-named-bounds, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28901893/why-is-main-window-of-type-double-optional.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The property `window` of `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol is declared like this:

```
optional var window: UIWindow? { get set }
```

That means that it is an **optional property** (in the sense that "the class implementing the `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol **is not requested to implement/have this property**", like when you have  `@optional` in Objective-C), and that property **is of optional type** `Optional<UIWindow>` (or `UIWindow?`).

That's why you have the double-optional type in the end, because that `window` property may or may not be implemented in realDelegate, and if it is, it will be itself of type `Optional<UIWindow>`/`UIWindow?`.

---

So basically what you want is to return the `window` property of your `realAppDelegate`… only if that `realAppDelegate` decided to declare that property itself (which it isn't requires to do, as it's `optional var`).

- If the `realAppDelegate` did not implement `window` itself, you probably intend to return a `nil` `UIWindow?` as a result.
- If your `realAppDelegate` did actually implement the `window` property, then you need to return it as is (wether this implementation returns an actual `UIWindow` or a `nil` one).

The easiest way to do that is to use the nil-coalescing operator `??` in Swift. `a ?? b` meaning that "if a is non-nil, then return a, but if a is nil, return b" (where if `a` is of type `T?`, then the whole expression is expected to return an object of type `T`, where in your case `T` is the type `UIWindow?`).

```
var window: UIWindow? {
    get {
        // If realAppDelegate.window (of type UIWindow??) is not implemented
        // then return nil. Otherwise, return its value (of type UIWindow?)
        return realAppDelegate.window ?? nil
        // That code is equivalent (but more concise) to this kind of code:
        //   if let w = realAppDelegate.window { return w } else return nil
    }
    ...
}
```

---

To implement the setter, that's another problem. According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26083377/swift-setting-an-optional-property-of-a-protocol), directly accessing to the setter of an optional property of a protocol doesn't seem to be possible. But you can imagine a hack to workaround this, by declaring another protocol that makes this `window` property requirement mandatory, then try to cast to it in the setter:

```
@objc protocol UIApplicationDelegateWithWindow : UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow? { get set }
}

class AppDelegateWrapper : UIApplicationDelegate {
    ...
    var window: UIWindow? {
        get {
            return realAppDelegate.window ?? nil
        }
        set {
            if let realAppDelWithWindow = realAppDelegate as? UIApplicationDelegateWithWindow
            {
                // Cast succeeded, so the 'window' property exists and is now accessible
                realAppDelWithWindow.window = newValue
            }
        }
    }
...
}
```

Comment: Can you expand your answer to show how you'd implement `set { … }`?

Comment: That's actually a very good question… and I'm afraid that's not possible in Swift (yet?) according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26083377/swift-setting-an-optional-property-of-a-protocol :-/

Comment: @AaronBrager I updated my answer with a suggestion on how to workaround and implement it. Quickly tested in a playground, seems to work as expected.

Comment: I haven't tested, but I guess that in the `UIApplicationDelegateWithWindow` protocol I created I could have only requested the `{ set }` to be implemented (no need to add unneeded contraints on the getter)

Answer (score 1):

The declaration of the property is

```
optional var window: UIWindow? { get set }
```

The `optional` in the beginning means that the property doesn't have to be there at all, that's the second `?`.

`UIApplicationDelegate` is a protocol, the class that implements it doesn't have to implement everything.