# How to assign value to this type in Swift?

Tags: string, swift, option-type

I'm using Swift as my project language,and there is a library written in Objective-C.The issue is that the property `apnsNickname`'s type is `String!?` in Swift.As the compiler's auto completion tells me.

[image]

I want to know how to assign a value to this type.The following assignment has a compiler error.

```
EaseMob.sharedInstance().chatManager.apnsNickname = "Mike"
```

> Cannot assign to the result of this expression

Can anyone help me out?

[image]
[image]

The definition of the property is:

```
@protocol IChatManagerSettingOptions <IChatManagerBase>

@optional

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *apnsNickname;

...

@end
```

Comment: "Mike" is actually of type `String`.

Comment: Still you need to typecasting! As swift is a "type safe" language

Comment: Also as you can see that there is "!" and "?" both, so it says that you specify that explicitly that it's a type of String or it will convert automatically

Comment: Can you show compile log?

Comment: @longpham The compiler log is `Cannot assign to the result of this expression`.

Comment: I think: `EaseMob.sharedInstance().chatManager.apnsNickname = "Mike"` is exact.

Comment: I don't think there's much sense or clearness in an optional property, and I can imagine this leading to problems.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29925097/1187415) to the referenced thread shows a workaround which is also discussed in https://devforums.apple.com/message/994834.